# How display a field error in a Grails-generated form when performing custom validation?

Tags: grails

I have a Grails generated form with the following field:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: applicantInstance, field: 'applicantName', 'error')} ">
<label for="applicantName">
    <g:message code="applicant.applicantName.label" default="Applicant Name" />

</label>
<g:textField name="applicantName" maxlength="50" value="${applicantInstance?.applicantName}"/>
</div>
```

I want to perform server side validation beyond the normal Grails validation, and redisplay the record if the validation fails.  I tried adding my own FieldError, but it does not work.

```
def error = new org.springframework.validation.FieldError("Applicant", "applicantName", "This name fails the custom server-side validation")
applicantInstance.errors.fieldErrors.add(error)
```

How display this field error in my Grails-generated form?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom validation beyound costraints declared in domain objects I suggest you to use [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects)